# A Perron-like formula

Tags: complex-analysis, dirichlet-series

From basic Dirichlet series ,if $f(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n^s},s=\sigma+it , \sigma>\sigma_0 $  where $\sigma_0$ is the abscissa of convergence, we know that : $$ \sum_{n<x}\frac{a_n}{n^s}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i \infty}f(s+z) \frac{x^z}{z}dz,  c>0 ,c>\sigma-\sigma_0$$. I tried using some other integrand to create a similar formula and i came to this: $$\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n^s}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)=$$ $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}-\frac{f(s+2z)}{z\sin(\pi z)} dz$$ , for $\Re{z}>0  $ . In order to get the result , one has to compute the integral on the right side. I used as a contour the semicircle from the right side of the vertical line $(c-iT,c+iT)$ which contains the poles $1,2,3,...,n,...$ of the integrand function. I think my result is right , but can somebody confirm it?

Comment: It suffices to check the formula when $a_n=0$ for all $n$ except $a_k=1$ for some positive integer $k$. Have you done that calculation?

Comment: @GregMartin yes, but your argument is valid only when assuming everything converges absolutely

Comment: Yes this is an assumption in my formula . I took it into account. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a harmonic sum hiding here which we now evaluate.

Put  $$L(s)  =  \sum_{n\ge   1}  \frac{a_n}{n^s}$$  with  abscissa  of
convergence $\sigma_0$ and introduce

$$S(x; z)= \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{a_n}{n^z}
\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2 n^2}\right)$$

The sum term is harmonic and  may be evaluated by inverting its Mellin
transform.

Recall the harmonic sum identity
$$\mathfrak{M}\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \lambda_k g(\mu_k x);s\right) =
\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} \right) g^*(s)$$
where $g^*(s)$ is the Mellin transform of $g(x).$

In the present case we have
$$\lambda_k = \frac{a_k}{k^z}, \quad \mu_k = k 
\quad \text{and} \quad
g(x) = \log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right).$$

We need the Mellin transform $g^*(s)$ of $g(x)$ which is
$$\int_0^\infty \log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right) x^{s-1} dx
\\ = \left[\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right) 
\frac{x^s}{s}\right]_0^\infty
+ 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x(1 +  x^2)} \frac{x^s}{s} dx
\\ = \frac{2}{s} 
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1 + x^2} x^{s-1} dx.$$

The fundamental  strip of  the term from  the integration by  parts is
$\langle 0,  2\rangle,$ which is  also the  fundamental strip  of the
second Mellin transform, call it $h^*(s)$ of $h(x).$

The  latter transform  is simple  -- use  a keyhole  contour  with the
branch  of the logarithm  producing arguments  between $0$  and $2\pi$
(branch cut  on the positive  real axis) and  two poles at  $x=\pm i.$
Above  the  cut  we  obtain  $h^*(s)$  and below  we  put  $x^{s-1}  =
\exp(\log(x)(s-1))$ to obtain $-h^*(s) \exp(2\pi i(s-1))$ so that

$$h^*(s) (1-\exp(2\pi i s)) = 2\pi i \times \frac{1}{2i} 
(\exp(i\pi (s-1)/2) - \exp(3 i\pi(s-1)/2))
\\ = 2\pi i \times \frac{1}{2i} 
(-i\exp(i\pi s/2) - i\exp(3 i\pi s/2))$$

and hence

$$h^*(s) = -i\pi\frac{\exp(i\pi s/2) + \exp(3 i\pi s/2)}
{1-\exp(2\pi i s)}
= -i\pi\frac{\exp(-i\pi s/2) + \exp(i\pi s/2)}
{\exp(-\pi i s)-\exp(\pi i s)}
\\ = i\pi \frac{2\cos(\pi s/2)}{2i\sin(\pi s)}
= \pi \frac{\cos(\pi s/2)}{\sin(\pi s)} = \frac{\pi}{2}
\frac{1}{\sin(\pi s/2)}.$$

Therefore $$g^*(s) = \frac{\pi}{s\sin(\pi s/2)}.$$

It follows that the Mellin transform $Q(s)$ of the harmonic sum 
$S(x;z)$ is given by

$$Q(s) = \frac{\pi}{s\sin(\pi s/2)} L(z+s)
\quad\text{because}\quad
\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} = 
\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{a_k}{k^z} \frac{1}{k^s}
= L(z+s)$$
for $\Re(z+s) > \sigma_0.$

The Mellin inversion integral here is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} Q(s)/x^s ds$$

where we choose $c$ in the intersection of $\langle 0,2\rangle$ and
$\Re(z+s) \gt \sigma_0.$ Putting $x=1$ we obtain the formula

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{a_n}{n^z}
\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} 
\frac{\pi}{s\sin(\pi s/2)} L(z+s) \; ds.}$$

Now of course we need to check the usefulness of this result.

For example, fixing first $z=4$ and $a_n = 1$ we get $L(s) = \zeta(s)$ 
and for $c$ we need $\Re(4+s) \gt 1$ so we may take $c=3/2$ to get

$$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{n^4}
\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{3/2-i\infty}^{3/2+i\infty} 
\frac{\pi}{s\sin(\pi s/2)} \zeta(s+4) \; ds.$$

Shifting the integral to the left for an expansion about zero yields

$$\frac{1}{4} + \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \frac{\pi}{3} + 2\zeta'(4)
\approx 0.709913984$$

when the  correct value is  $0.7087317181.$ This simply says  that the
remainder integral does not vanish. Here we observe cancelation of the
poles  from  the  sine  term   by  the  trivial  zeroes  of  the  zeta
function. With $z$ an odd  integer numerics indicate an expansion that
does not converge.

As another example we get

$$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{\tau(n)}{n^4}
\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{3/2-i\infty}^{3/2+i\infty} 
\frac{\pi}{s\sin(\pi s/2)} \zeta^2(s+4) \; ds$$

with the divisor function. The expansion abouz zero produces

$$-\frac{1}{8} + \frac{\pi^4}{36} + \frac{2}{45} \pi^4 \zeta'(4)
- \frac{2}{3}\gamma\pi - \frac{\pi}{9} \approx 0.7244875166$$

when the correct value is $0.7246090404.$

Finally consider the sum-of-divisors function to obtain

$$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{\sigma(n)}{n^4}
\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{3/2-i\infty}^{3/2+i\infty} 
\frac{\pi}{s\sin(\pi s/2)} \zeta(s+4) \zeta(s+3) \; ds$$

We get

$$-\frac{1}{48} + \frac{1}{6}\gamma\pi^2 + \zeta'(2) 
+ \frac{\pi^2}{12} + \frac{1}{45} \pi^4 \zeta'(3) 
+ 2\zeta'(4) \zeta(3) + \frac{\pi}{6} 
\approx 0.7426221350$$

with the true value being $0.74267514.$

Using a function like $2^{v_2(n)}$  with $v_2(n)$  the
largest power of two that divides $n$ we get

$$L(s) = \zeta(s) \frac{1-1/2^{s}}{1-2/2^{s}}$$

and a Fourier series due to the poles at $\rho_k = 1+2\pi i k/\log(2)$
appears.  We   have  deliberately  refrained   from  using  arithmetic
functions whose Dirichlet series contains inverse zeta function terms,
where the non-trivial zeroes of the zeta function enter into the game.

**Summary.**   An  interesting  formula   whose  use   for  numeric
approximations is limited  and which does not appear  to produce novel
closed  forms, possibly  meriting additional  investigation  e.g.  for
smaller $x$  that yield better  convergence (when we take  $x=1/10$ in
the  first  example  we  obtain $4.8618872988137896537$  which  has  a
remarkable $20$ good  digits, a phenomenon that was  observed with the
other two examples as well)  or cases where $L(s)$ in conjunction with
the sine term might produce a functional equation.

Comment: sorry but I don't understand why you need such a loing answer

Comment: Wow great answer and very useful results. Good summary also. Thank you for showing so much interest in my question . Your insight was very useful. I am undergraduate and i would like to study more about Dirichlet Series and L functions. Do you have a book to suggest?

Comment: This is very kind of you considering I did not answer your question exactly! I recommend Flajolet & Sedgewick, *Mellin Transform Asymptotics*, Technical Report RR 2956, INRIA, Roquencourt, 1996.

Answer (score 1):

**If $F(s) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k k^{-s}$ converge abslutely for $Re(s) > 0$** then on $Re(s) > \epsilon$  : $F(s)$ is analytic and $|F(s)| = \mathcal{O}(1)$ so that

- For $c \in (0,1)$ and $Re(s) > 0$ : $$\int_{c - i\infty}^{c+i \infty} \frac{F(s+2z)}{z \sin(\pi z)}dz$$
  converges absolutely.
- With $R_{c,d,T}$ the boundary of the rectangle $c\pm i T,d \pm i T$ ($d > c,d \not \in \mathbb{Z}$) you have by the residue theorem
  $$\int_{R_{c,d,T}}\frac{F(s+2z)}{z \sin(\pi z)}dz = 2i\pi\sum_{n \in (c,d)} Res(\frac{F(s+2z)}{z \sin(\pi z)}, n) = 2i\pi\sum_{n \in (c,d)} (-1)^n\frac{F(s+ 2n)}{n} $$
- and since $ \frac{F(s+2z)}{z \sin(\pi z)}$ decreases exponentially as $Im(z) \to \infty$ and $\int_{d-iT}^{d+iT} \frac{F(s+z)}{z \sin(\pi z)}dz \to 0$ as $d \to \infty$ and that everything converges absolutely, you have

$$\int_{c - i\infty}^{c+i \infty} \frac{F(s+2z)}{z \sin(\pi z)}dz= \lim_{d,T \to \infty}\int_{R_{c,d,T}}\frac{F(s+2z)}{z \sin(\pi z)}dz = 2i\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{F(s+2 n)}{ n}  $$ $$= 2i\pi\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k k^{-s}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n \frac{k^{- 2n}}{ n}= 2i\pi\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k k^{-s} \log(1+k^{-2})$$

The conclusion is that you need $F$ to be analytic, and everything to converges (if it doesn't converge absolutely, you have to be very careful when taking the $\lim_{d, T \to\infty}$ and when inverting $\sum_k \sum_n$)

Comment: O suppose f is a convergent dirichlet series in the hal plane of absolute convergence. In the proof of the formula i consider the series absolutely convergent in order to change the integration-summation order